# java.lang.ArithmeticException thrown without stack trace and without message

Tags: java, exception, grpc-java

```
@Override
public StreamObserver<MdtDialoutArgs> mdtDialout(StreamObserver<MdtDialoutArgs> responseObserver) {

    return new StreamObserver<MdtDialoutArgs>() {

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable t) {
            logger.warn( "Encountered error in mdtDialout");
        }

        @Override
        public void onCompleted() {
            responseObserver.onCompleted();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(MdtDialoutArgs arg0) {
           try {
                ....
                ....
                ...
          } catch (Exception e) {
               logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
          }
     }
```

Above code throws a java.lang.ArithmeticException without stack trace and without message. I am not creating/throwing empty ArithmeticException in the try block. 
What java method call/code can throw java.lang.ArithmeticException without stack trace and without error message?

And Has any one seen an ArithmeticException in java with no message before?
Log output:

> null java.lang.ArithmeticException

Comment: Which logging framework are you using? You need to log the exception _as an exception_ so that the framework logs the stack trace.  Also, you omitted all code that might contain an arithmetic problem. so we cannot help you.  Log the complete exception, then [edit] your post to include the stack trace and the code that caused the exception.

Comment: there are no stack trace printed and e.getMessage is null.. this is log4j framework.  I am seeing other exception printedwith stack trace.  My question :Has any one seen an ArithmeticException in java with no message before?

Comment: There is no stack trace printed because in your `catch (Exception e)` block you do not print it, you only log an error with the exception message ***but not the stack trace***.  This is why I asked which looger framework you are using, to lookup the API for logging an exception that include the stack trace.

Comment: I'm looking into a `java.lang.ArithmeticException: null` with no stack trace @suresh did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 5):

For some frequently thrown exceptions, JVM will make an optimization to hide the stack trace.
When the server restart, the stack trace of this exception will show again.

**Optimized version**

> java.lang.ArithmeticException: null

**After restart**

> java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero at
> java.math.BigDecimal.divideAndRound(BigDecimal.java:4106) at
> java.math.BigDecimal.divide(BigDecimal.java:5153)

You can add VM option **-XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow** to close this optimization.

Answer (score 1):

From the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ArithmeticException.html):

> ArithmeticException is thrown when an exceptional arithmetic condition
>   has occurred. For example, an integer "divide by zero" throws an
>   instance of this class. ArithmeticException objects may be constructed
>   by the virtual machine as if [suppression were disabled and/or the
>   stack trace was not writable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#Throwable-java.lang.String-java.lang.Throwable-boolean-boolean-).

Are you constructing Throwable objects in that block in a a unique way?

Comment: I am not throwing any exception or throwable objects.